# Having an issue with excel "text to columns" feature - need to remove space

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 100's of rows of data, each row containing a list of multiple items separated by comma. for example:

a fox, a frog, a dog, candy, 
tyler, daren, hogge, laura, 
cat in the hat, remembering your favorite day, having a fun time

etc

as you can see, its not a simple "lastname, firstname" separation.

the issue im having is when i use text to columns, i can easily separate by comma, but im then left with a space before every second item in the list. I need to remove the space after each comma (but not EVERY space after each word!)

I cant just select "comma" and "space" in the delimiters option, because then it removes EVERY space between words (eg 'havingafuntime') when i only want to remove THE ONE space after the comma.

I know i can use "trim" - but im wondering if theres a way to remove the space WHILE SEPARATING THE TEXT TO COLUMNS, all in one swoop.

Comment: I originally thought a custom delimiter would work but it appears that the problem is you can only have a single character as a delimiter.  You will either need to manipulate your text before or after you do the text to columns.  Or you will need to write a VBA script that will let you define your own delimiter.  If you do not mind doing a step before you do text to column I have an approach that should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

When working "normal" with excel you can simply left out any formulas for this case.

Instead of the `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ",",")` you can simply select the range you want to be corrected (like the whole A:A column) and press Ctrl+H (replace). Set "Find What" to `", "` and "replace with" to `","` (without the `"`). Hit replace all the to do it for the whole selection (non selected cells won't be replaced).

The build-in "Text to columns" can not be manipulated in a way to do it in one step.

**EDIT**:

Doing it as a one-click-macro just this 4 lines should do what you desire:

```
Sub text2cols()
  Selection.Replace ", ", ","
  Selection.TextToColumns Selection.Resize(1, 1), 1, , , , , True
End Sub
```

Just select the range you want to seperate and run the macro ;)

Comment: I prefer this option as it does it all in place with no need for copy paste

Comment: It all depends on the times he is in need of doing this action. Still he could record a macro while doing this 2 actions to do it in one step later.

Answer (score 0):

in the cell adjacent to the start of the column you are going to convert using text to columns, enter the following formula and copy down.

```
=substitute(A1,", ",",")

This will remove the space after every ,
```

Then copy and paste as value the resulting column.

Then perform your Text to Columns operation using , as you delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use Power Query.

1. Depending on your version of excel you should be able to download an install Power Query by googling "Download Power query for Excel 20X"
2. click in your data set
3. On Power query tab you will see "From Table" (in excel 2016 its already in data tab, you do not have to download it)
4. choose if your data has header or not
5. Go to Transform
6. Under Split column choose by delimiter
7. Choose comma
8. Under Format you will see Trim
9. Go to Home tab choose close and load
   and you're done

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I found this doing a google search because I had the same problem as the OP. However, upon reading some of the suggestions it came to me that I can use the Find & Replace feature. I selected the column in question and did the following:

Find what: ", " (without quotes - used to show space)
Replace with: , (no space)

Essentially this made the list go from: a fox, a frog, a dog, candy, tyler, daren, hogge, laura, cat in the hat, remembering your favorite day, having a fun time

And changed it into this: a fox,a frog,a dog,candy,tyler,daren,hogge,laura,cat in the hat,remembering your favorite day,having a fun time

Then I just used the Text To Column function delimited by comma and it worked beautifully.

I hope this helps someone else out.